# Libelf creates corrupted output file, even when changing nothing

Tags: c, elf

I'm trying to use libelf to edit some things in ELF binaries, but so far I'm unable to even write the binary out without corrupting it. This sample:

```
#include <libelf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <gelf.h>

int main() {
    elf_version(EV_CURRENT);
    int fd = open("elftest", O_RDWR, 0);
    assert(fd >= 0);
    Elf *elf = elf_begin(fd, ELF_C_RDWR, NULL);
    assert(elf != NULL);
    assert(elf_kind(elf) == ELF_K_ELF);
    assert(elf_update(elf, ELF_C_WRITE) != -1);
    elf_end(elf);
    close(fd);
}
```

which should just read in `elftest` and write it back out unchanged instead converts a working C hello world into a program that segfaults immediately (according to gdb, even before main is called).
The first discrepancy I noticed with `readelf -h` was that it moved the start of section headers back somewhat, and also reports that

```
readelf: Warning: the .dynamic section is not contained within the dynamic segment
```

What is causing `libelf` to alter the executable even when nothing is actually changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which should just read in elftest and write it back out unchanged instead converts a working C hello world into a program that segfaults immediately

This sure looks like a bug in `libelf`.

Adding this line immediately after `elf_open()` fixes your program:

```
    Elf *elf = elf_begin(fd, ELF_C_RDWR, NULL);
    elf_flagelf(elf, ELF_C_SET, ELF_F_LAYOUT);  // add this
```

but I don't think it should be necessary.

P.S. I know this is just an example, but putting *functional* parts of your program inside `assert()` is a really bad idea. Doing this:

```
  assert(elf_update(elf, ELF_C_WRITE) != -1);
```

will make you sorry sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experimenting with `libelf` and found the same issue. After investigating it seems that `libelf` moves the sections around without reworking the program segments when using the "Library layout" mode.

From my understanding, when a program start, the program headers are read to tell how parts of the file should be loaded. For example the `.text` section containing code ends up mapped to a memory area with execution permissions, and `.rodata` containing static data ends up in a read-only segment.

See this example:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

`readelf -l -S` shows the following on the working executable:

```
There are 29 section headers, starting at offset 0x3660:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         0000000000000318  00000318
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 2] .note.gnu.pr[...] NOTE             0000000000000338  00000338
       0000000000000030  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [ 3] .note.gnu.bu[...] NOTE             0000000000000368  00000368
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 4] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE             000000000000038c  0000038c
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 5] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH         00000000000003b0  000003b0
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       6     0     8
  [ 6] .dynsym           DYNSYM           00000000000003d8  000003d8
       0000000000000090  0000000000000018   A       7     1     8
  [ 7] .dynstr           STRTAB           0000000000000468  00000468
       0000000000000088  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 8] .gnu.version      VERSYM           00000000000004f0  000004f0
       000000000000000c  0000000000000002   A       6     0     2
  [ 9] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED          0000000000000500  00000500
       0000000000000030  0000000000000000   A       7     1     8
  [10] .rela.dyn         RELA             0000000000000530  00000530
       00000000000000c0  0000000000000018   A       6     0     8
  [11] .init             PROGBITS         0000000000001000  00001000
       000000000000001b  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS         0000000000001020  00001020
       0000000000000010  0000000000000010  AX       0     0     16
  [13] .plt.got          PROGBITS         0000000000001030  00001030
       0000000000000010  0000000000000010  AX       0     0     16
  [14] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000001040  00001040
       00000000000000f8  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
  [15] .fini             PROGBITS         0000000000001138  00001138
       000000000000000d  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [16] .rodata           PROGBITS         0000000000002000  00002000
       0000000000000004  0000000000000004  AM       0     0     4
  [17] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS         0000000000002004  00002004
       000000000000002c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [18] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         0000000000002030  00002030
       0000000000000094  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [19] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY       0000000000003df0  00002df0
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [20] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY       0000000000003df8  00002df8
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [21] .dynamic          DYNAMIC          0000000000003e00  00002e00
       00000000000001c0  0000000000000010  WA       7     0     8
  [22] .got              PROGBITS         0000000000003fc0  00002fc0
       0000000000000040  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [23] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000004000  00003000
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [24] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000004010  00003010
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [25] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00003010
       000000000000002b  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [26] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00003040
       0000000000000348  0000000000000018          27    18     8
  [27] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00003388
       00000000000001c9  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [28] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  00003551
       000000000000010c  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  D (mbind), l (large), p (processor specific)

Elf file type is DYN (Position-Independent Executable file)
Entry point 0x1040
There are 13 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040
                 0x00000000000002d8 0x00000000000002d8  R      0x8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000318 0x0000000000000318 0x0000000000000318
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x00000000000005f0 0x00000000000005f0  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000
                 0x0000000000000145 0x0000000000000145  R E    0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000
                 0x00000000000000c4 0x00000000000000c4  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002df0 0x0000000000003df0 0x0000000000003df0
                 0x0000000000000220 0x0000000000000228  RW     0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000002e00 0x0000000000003e00 0x0000000000003e00
                 0x00000000000001c0 0x00000000000001c0  RW     0x8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000338 0x0000000000000338 0x0000000000000338
                 0x0000000000000030 0x0000000000000030  R      0x8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000368 0x0000000000000368 0x0000000000000368
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      0x4
  GNU_PROPERTY   0x0000000000000338 0x0000000000000338 0x0000000000000338
                 0x0000000000000030 0x0000000000000030  R      0x8
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0000000000002004 0x0000000000002004 0x0000000000002004
                 0x000000000000002c 0x000000000000002c  R      0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000002df0 0x0000000000003df0 0x0000000000003df0
                 0x0000000000000210 0x0000000000000210  R      0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.gnu.property .note.gnu.build-id .note.ABI-tag .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn 
   03     .init .plt .plt.got .text .fini 
   04     .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   05     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .data .bss 
   06     .dynamic 
   07     .note.gnu.property 
   08     .note.gnu.build-id .note.ABI-tag 
   09     .note.gnu.property 
   10     .eh_frame_hdr 
   11     
   12     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got
```

But after the corruption:

```
There are 29 section headers, starting at offset 0x1070:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         0000000000000318  00000318
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 2] .note.gnu.pr[...] NOTE             0000000000000338  00000338
       0000000000000030  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [ 3] .note.gnu.bu[...] NOTE             0000000000000368  00000368
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 4] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE             000000000000038c  0000038c
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 5] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH         00000000000003b0  000003b0
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       6     0     8
  [ 6] .dynsym           DYNSYM           00000000000003d8  000003d8
       0000000000000090  0000000000000018   A       7     1     8
  [ 7] .dynstr           STRTAB           0000000000000468  00000468
       0000000000000088  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 8] .gnu.version      VERSYM           00000000000004f0  000004f0
       000000000000000c  0000000000000002   A       6     0     2
  [ 9] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED          0000000000000500  00000500
       0000000000000030  0000000000000000   A       7     1     8
  [10] .rela.dyn         RELA             0000000000000530  00000530
       00000000000000c0  0000000000000018   A       6     0     8
  [11] .init             PROGBITS         0000000000001000  000005f0
       000000000000001b  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS         0000000000001020  00000610
       0000000000000010  0000000000000010  AX       0     0     16
  [13] .plt.got          PROGBITS         0000000000001030  00000620
       0000000000000010  0000000000000010  AX       0     0     16
  [14] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000001040  00000630
       00000000000000f8  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
  [15] .fini             PROGBITS         0000000000001138  00000728
       000000000000000d  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [16] .rodata           PROGBITS         0000000000002000  00000738
       0000000000000004  0000000000000004  AM       0     0     4
  [17] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS         0000000000002004  0000073c
       000000000000002c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [18] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         0000000000002030  00000768
       0000000000000094  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [19] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY       0000000000003df0  00000800
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [20] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY       0000000000003df8  00000808
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [21] .dynamic          DYNAMIC          0000000000003e00  00000810
       00000000000001c0  0000000000000010  WA       7     0     8
  [22] .got              PROGBITS         0000000000003fc0  000009d0
       0000000000000040  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [23] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000004000  00000a10
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [24] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000004010  00000a20
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [25] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000a20
       000000000000002b  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [26] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00000a50
       0000000000000348  0000000000000018          27    18     8
  [27] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00000d98
       00000000000001c9  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [28] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  00000f61
       000000000000010c  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  D (mbind), l (large), p (processor specific)

Elf file type is DYN (Position-Independent Executable file)
Entry point 0x1040
There are 13 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040
                 0x00000000000002d8 0x00000000000002d8  R      0x8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000318 0x0000000000000318 0x0000000000000318
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x00000000000005f0 0x00000000000005f0  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000
                 0x0000000000000145 0x0000000000000145  R E    0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000
                 0x00000000000000c4 0x00000000000000c4  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002df0 0x0000000000003df0 0x0000000000003df0
                 0x0000000000000220 0x0000000000000228  RW     0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000002e00 0x0000000000003e00 0x0000000000003e00
                 0x00000000000001c0 0x00000000000001c0  RW     0x8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000338 0x0000000000000338 0x0000000000000338
                 0x0000000000000030 0x0000000000000030  R      0x8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000368 0x0000000000000368 0x0000000000000368
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      0x4
  GNU_PROPERTY   0x0000000000000338 0x0000000000000338 0x0000000000000338
                 0x0000000000000030 0x0000000000000030  R      0x8
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0000000000002004 0x0000000000002004 0x0000000000002004
                 0x000000000000002c 0x000000000000002c  R      0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000002df0 0x0000000000003df0 0x0000000000003df0
                 0x0000000000000210 0x0000000000000210  R      0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.gnu.property .note.gnu.build-id .note.ABI-tag .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn 
   03     
   04     
   05     .bss 
   06     
   07     .note.gnu.property 
   08     .note.gnu.build-id .note.ABI-tag 
   09     .note.gnu.property 
   10     
   11     
   12
```

Focusing on the `.text` section, it was originally at offset `0x00001040` which mapped to segment 3 (starting at offset `0x00001000` and with the executable bit set `E`).
After processing by `libelf`, `.text` was moved to offset `0x00000630` which no longer maps to the executable section.
Looking at the "Section to Segment mapping" reported by `readelf` we can clearly see that something is wrong.

As mentioned in another answer, you can get around this by using the "Application Controlled layout" mode, but you get to do all the annoying work of updating offsets and sizes all over if you are making modifications to the ELF sections.

I hope this is useful, I learned quite a lot while investigating.